# Plotting MLLib results (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, visualization, apache-spark-mllib

I am searching for an easy way to quickly visualise MLLib results such as Decision Trees, K-Means Clusters etc. My Zeppelin Notebook gives me nice results for SparkSQL, however the graphs are very limited and can't handle things like decision trees.

I know about the `display` command [within the databricks notebooks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/27/visualizing-machine-learning-models.html). I am searching for a way to realize something simular, since I can not use databricks notebooks directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnuplot after saving your results in files http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/
Or D3.JS https://d3js.org/ but you need some knowledge in javascript or use python just for plotting because there are many librairies like mathplotlib